# How can I write migrations to insert records using phinx?

Tags: php, mysql, migration

I'm using [phinx](http://docs.phinx.org/) to handle the migration on a new project, now I need to create a new table and insert some rows to it, I have:

```
$tableStatus = $this->table('status');
$tableStatus->addColumn('code', 'string');
$tableStatus->addColumn('description', 'string');
$tableStatus->save();
```

This add the new table but I couldn't find at the documentation how to insert rows, but it seems possible:

> The AbstractMigration Class All Phinx migrations extend from the
>   AbstractMigration class. This class provides the necessary support to
>   create your database migrations. Database migrations can transform
>   your database in many ways such as creating new tables, **inserting
>   rows**, adding indexes and modifying columns.

It is possible? How can I do it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As  igrossiter pointed out, there is a method for this, the name of the method is *insert*

```
use Phinx\Migration\AbstractMigration;

class NewStatus extends AbstractMigration
{
    protected $statusId = 1234; //It'd be nice to use an entity constant instead of magic numbers, but that's up to you.
    protected $statusName = 'In Progress';

    /**
    * Migrate Up.
    */
    public function up()
    {
        $columns = ['id', 'name'];
        $data = [[$this->statusId, $this->statusName]];
        $table = $this->table('status');
        $table->insert($columns, $data);
        $table->saveData();   
    }

    /**
    * Migrate Down.
    */
    public function down()
    {
        $this->execute('Delete from status where id = ' . $this->statusId);
    }
}
```

**Edit as of December 2nd, 2015**

This method's signature will change in future stable versions to something like

```
$data = [
    ['id' => 1, 'name' => 'foo'],
    ['id' => 2, 'name' => 'bar']
];
$table = $this->table('status');
$table->insert($data);
```

More [info here](https://github.com/robmorgan/phinx/pull/639#event-480065126)

Answer (score 10):

You can do it. Read documentation for more information.

http://docs.phinx.org/en/latest/migrations.html#executing-queries

```
use Phinx\Migration\AbstractMigration;

class MyNewMigration extends AbstractMigration
{
    /**
    * Migrate Up.
    */
    public function up()
    {
        // execute()
        $count = $this->execute('insert into users(id, name) values (5, "john")'); 
    }

    /**
     * Migrate Down.
     */
    public function down()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping something like `$table->insert(array('column' => 'value'));` but this worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Run this command to generate StatusMigration class:

```sh
php vendor/bin/phinx create StatusMigration
```

2. Edit that file like:

```php
<?php

use Phinx\Migration\AbstractMigration;

class StatusMigration extends AbstractMigration
{
    public function change()
    {
        $this->table('status')
            ->addColumn('code', 'string')
            ->addColumn('description', 'string')
            ->create();
    }
}
```

3. You can use Phinx's database seeding mechanism to insert rows into tables. First run following command:

```sh
php vendor/bin/phinx seed:create StatusSeeder
```

It will generate StatusSeeder.php file in Phinx's seeds folder.

4. Edit StatusSeader.php like:

```php
use Phinx\Seed\AbstractSeed;

class StatusSeeder extends AbstractSeed
{
    public function run()
    {
        $data = [
            ['code' => 'c1', 'description' => 'Some description'],
            ['code' => 'c2', 'description' => 'Another description'],
        ];

        $this->table('status')
            ->insert($data)
            ->save();
    }
}
```

5. Now, run following commands to create table and seed data:

```sh
php vendor/bin/phinx migrate
php vendor/bin/phinx seed:run
```

Answer (score -3):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30712896/cakephp-how-to-use-migration-to-insert-records) has a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30713138/195648) using CakePHP 3's [Migrations](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/migrations.html) plugin:

```
public function up() {
    // Save records to the newly created schema
    $UsersTable = TableRegistry::get('Users');
    $user = $UsersTable->newEntity();

    $user->name = 'Joe Bloggs';
    $user->email = 'joe@example.com';

    $UsersTable->save($user);
}
```

Comment: The question is not CakePHP related