# Cakephp: How to use migration to insert records

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm using CakePHP v3.x and I'm trying to figure out how to insert some records via the migrations tool. [The documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/migrations.html) only lists methods for modifying the schema. Will I need to insert records manually with raw SQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CakePHP 3's Migration plugin is a Phinx wrapper plugin, so adding records can be done using the `up()` method:-

```
public function up() {
    // Save records to the newly created schema
}

public function down() {
    // Remove records
}
```

For example, you could add a new user using `TableRegistry` on `up`:-

```
public function up() {
    // Save records to the newly created schema
    $UsersTable = TableRegistry::get('Users');
    $user = $UsersTable->newEntity();

    $user->name = 'Joe Bloggs';
    $user->email = 'joe@example.com';

    $UsersTable->save($user);
}
```

If using `TableRegistry` don't forget to include `use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;` at the top of the migration file.

For CakeDC's Migration plugin you can insert records using the [callbacks](https://github.com/CakeDC/migrations/blob/master/Docs/Documentation/Migrations.md) in the relevant migration file:-

```
public function after($direction) {
    if ($direction === 'up') {
        // Save records to the newly created schema
    } elseif ($direction === 'down') {
        // Remove records
    }
}
```

NOTE: If you are using the Postgres driver, there is currently a [bug](https://github.com/cakephp/migrations/issues/83) which requires a small workaround to make this work.

Comment: CakePHp 3.x ships with its own migrations plugin (**https://github.com/cakephp/migrations**), which is a Phinx wrapper, are you sure that this applies here?

Comment: My mistake, I like working with CakeDC's plugin. I've updated my answer to show how to do it with the default plugin too.

Comment: kk, just wasn't sure as I haven't used the migrations plugin yet. I think it should be noted that in that case one indeed has to [**use raw SQL**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28265669/how-can-i-write-migrations-to-insert-records-using-phinx), as there seem to be no insert (wrapper) methods. **https://github.com/robmorgan/phinx/issues/96**

Comment: @ndm my understanding was that you could use Cake's ORM in the migrations for inserting data. However, every implementation of migrations I've seen has used raw SQL for handling the migration which doesn't seem correct to me.

Comment: Mmm, that might be true... I'll give it a try later on before I'll continue spreading potential false information :)

Comment: Ok, it indeed works, you can use the ORM or the underlying lower level database layer to insert rows. Not sure though if there might be any side effects with regards to cached schemas.

Comment: @ndm do I simply add the "uses" at the top and then $this->loadModel(...) ?

Comment: @SDP No, the `loadModel()` method is part of [**the `ModelAwareTrait` trait**](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Datasource.ModelAwareTrait.html), it's not used in genereated migration files. If you'd wanted to use that method, then you'd have to incorporate the trait. However I'd probably simply directly use the `TableRegistry` class to [**retrieve a table instance**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#getting-instances-of-a-table-class).

Comment: @ndm gotcha. Should this be it's own answer?

Comment: @SDP Not neccessarily, drmonkeyninja could add it to his answer.

Comment: @SDP I've added an example using `TableRegistry` to my answer.

Comment: Looks like some time ago, an `insert()` method was added, however It's [**not documented**](https://github.com/robmorgan/phinx/pull/639) yet **https://github.com/robmorgan/phinx/pull/457**